# A light black theme for Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, design, meta

Currently, there is a bluish theme for Meta Stack Exchange, which is not catchy for the eyes, since it doesn't follow the blackish theme for meta sites (I guess it's there to show the difference between a regular site and a meta)

Can we have a same type of theme for Meta Stack Exchange too?

Comment: “which is not catchy for our eyes” – Works fine for my eyes…

Comment: @poke Take a look at all the meta sites in our stackexchange and then see the difference.  Also look at the whole theme fonts, button, etc., they are not catchy look.  This is a suggestion by me and my colleagues.

Comment: I disagree. I think the theme is just fine. You just need to get used to it.

Comment: Meta... Meta is not... Meta is not... pretty? *How dare you say so!*

Comment: There's no "regular site" attached to this Meta, the sky is the limit ;)

Comment: @brasofilo I see what you did there.

Comment: I really liked the old color scheme and will miss it.

Comment: @3ventic can go but need some time.. since many disagree with my thoughts..

Comment: @brasofilo I think you missed stackexchange.com.. the kind of theme which I want for meta is there :(

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy hmm.. just look at the stackexchange.com ..it would be g8 if we have something like that... to be true I like the design but I dont want for meta...

Answer (score -2):

They should have moved the color to the Meta Stack Exchange site and created a new color scheme for Meta Stack Overflow. It would have fit much better, and alerted people to the change.